Which is in Redux Toolkit the type of a `builder.mutation` return value?
I've setup my Redux-Toolkit in my Nextjs application.
I've a mutation, setup like this:
postCar: builder.mutation<Car, CarEndpointPostParams>({
  query: ({ body = {} }) => ({
    url: "/api/cars",
    method: "POST",
    body,
  }),
}),

And this mutation is exported as usePostCarMutation
In one of my component, AddCar.tsx I am using this generated Redux-Toolkit hook:
const [postCar, result] = usePostCarMutation();

This postCar is provided to a child component, AddCarForm.tsx as a property.
I am trying to understand which is the type of the prop postCar of AddCarForm.tsx, unsuccessfully.
ATTEMPT 1
postCar: typeof api.endpoints.postCar

ATTEMPT 2
postCar: MutationDefinition<
  Car,
  BaseQueryFn,
  any,
  CarEndpointPostParams,
  any
>

ATTEMPT 3
postCar: MutationTrigger<MutationDefinition<
  Car,
  BaseQueryFn,
  any,
  CarEndpointPostParams,
  any
>>

Any ideas?


I am trying to understand which is the type of the prop postCar of
AddCarForm.tsx

The useMutation hook is typed as follows:

type UseMutation = (
  options?: UseMutationStateOptions,
) => [UseMutationTrigger, UseMutationResult | SelectedUseMutationResult]


Your postCar trigger function is type UserMutationTrigger:

type UseMutationTrigger<T> = (arg: any) => Promise<
  { data: T } | { error: BaseQueryError | SerializedError }
& {
  requestId: string // A string generated by RTK Query
  abort: () => void // A method to cancel the mutation promise
  unwrap: () => Promise<T> // A method to unwrap the mutation call and provide the raw response/error
  reset: () => void // A method to manually unsubscribe from the mutation call and reset the result to the uninitialized state
}


Where T is the return type you specified in the endpoint, e.g. Car, so it results in a postCar type that looks like this:
type UseMutationTrigger<Car> = (arg: any) => Promise<
  { data: Car } | { error: BaseQueryError | SerializedError }

> & {
  requestId: string
  abort: () => void
  unwrap: () => Promise<Car>
  reset: () => void
}


This postCar is provided to a child component, AddCarForm.tsx as a
property.

A postCar prop type would be something like: postCar: UseMutationTrigger<Car> in any consuming component.
There is a TypedMutationTrigger type you can use:
import { TypedMutationTrigger } from "@reduxjs/toolkit/dist/query/react";

export type PostCarTriggerFn = TypedMutationTrigger<
  Car,
  CarEndpointPostParams,
  any
>;

Or you can get it from the usePostCarMutation hook's return type:
export type PostCarTriggerFn = ReturnType<typeof usePostCarMutation>[0];

Type the postCar prop:
postCar: PostCarTriggerFn;

Note/Recommendation
Doing this goes a bit against the design-philosophy of Redux and RTK. Instead of passing the postCar trigger function down as props to children components, they should instead also just use the generated usePostCarMutation hook and access their own "copy" of the postCar trigger function. RTK and RTK-Query will cache results based on the args passed to the mutation, and return cached results. If two components make the same mutation request, i.e. same args, they see the same results.

Thanks for the answe, and also for the note at the bottom. I will try to refactor in that direction too. Helps in avoiding to forward these extra prop

@axel Welcome, happy to help. Cheers and good luck!
